# getting bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0 error when try to run postgresql query from nodejs app

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pgadmin

getting the error

> bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0

when try to run postgresql query from nodejs app but same working in pgadmin

Below mentioned query I am trying to run :

```
 query="select array_agg(zonename) from bitargetstg.tax_program_zones where coalesce(SHAPE_Area,0) >0 and (ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromEWKT(Geometry),"+"ST_GeomFromText(\'POINT($1  $2)\')) or ST_intersects(ST_GeomFromEWKT(Geometry), ST_GeomFromText(\'POINT($1  $2)\')))";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no parameter substitution in a string literal, so `$1` and `$2` are taken literally.